# im not sure if i implement correctly the cleaning method in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm not sure if I'm implementing the clean and the  clean_ methods correctly. In the documentation it says that we should call them, but where? we have to call them because at the moment of trying to go through form.is_valid() the data comes out as not validated and my question would be what I have to do heres my model:

```
class Users(models.Model):
       USERNAME_FIELD = models.CharField(max_length=90, blank=False, null=False,   primary_key=True) 
       LASTNAME_FIELD = models.CharField(max_length=90, null=False, blank=False)
       USERAGE_FIELD = models.IntegerField(null = True )
       USER_IMAGE_FIELD = models.ImageField(null = True, blank = False, upload_to='media/')

       USERMAIL_FIELD = models.EmailField()
       USERPSSWD_FIELD = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
       CONFPSSWD_FIELD = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     def clean(self):
       if (len(self.USERNAME_FIELD) = 0):
           raise ValidationError(_('not empty space'))

     def __str__(self):
           return self.USERNAME_FIELD
```

and heres my forms:

```
from django import forms

from .models import Users

from django.forms import ModelForm

from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

from django.forms import formset_factory

from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class Usersform(ModelForm):
class Meta:
      model = Users
      fields = '__all__'
      labels = {

       'USERNAME_FIELD': _('Nombre del Usuario:'),
       'LASTNAME_FIELD': _('Apellido del Usuario'),
       'USERAGE_FIELD': _('Edad del Usuario:'),
       'USER_IMAGE_FIELD': _('Foto del Usuario:'),
       'USERMAIL_FIELD': _('Email del Usuario:'),
       'USERPSSWD_FIELD': _('Contraseña:'),
       'CONFPSSWD_FIELD': _('Confirma la Contraseña:'),

}

def clean_USERAGE_FIELD(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data['USERAGE_FIELD']
    if (data < 18):
       raise ValidationError('you cant sign up youre to young')

    return data

def clean_USERMAIL_FIELD(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data['USERMAIL_FIELD']
    if (len(data) == 0 ):
    raise ValidationError('no empty spaces')
    return data

def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(Usersform, self).clean()
    self.USERNAME_FIELD = cleaned_data.get("USERNAME_FIELD")
    self.LASTNAME_FIELD = cleaned_data.get("LASTNAME_FIELD")
    self.USER_IMAGE_FIELD = cleaned_data.get("USER_IMAGE_FIELD")
    self.USERPSSWD_FIELD = cleaned_data.get("USERPSSWD_FIELD")
    self.CONFPSSWD_FIELD = cleaned_data.get("CONFPSSWD_FIELD")
    if (self.USERPSSWD_FIELD != self.CONFPSSWD_FIELD):
        raise ValidationError("pass no coincide")
    return cleaned_data
```

and heres my view :

```
class Sign_UpView(View):
      template_name = "register.html"
      form_class = Usersform

      def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
          form = self.form_class()
          return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form})
      
      def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
          form = self.form_class(request.POST)
          print(request.POST)
          if form.is_valid():
             try:
               form.clean()
               HttpResponse('redirected') 
             except:
                 print("error")
          return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form})
```

please i need help

Comment: you just have to call clean method before using save() method,

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).